# Python function returning Null type data

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, fibonacci, nonetype

I'm a trying to calculate the 'nth Fibonacci % m ' for the given values.
(Using the pisano's series).
Here is the message that the terminal is displaying.

**error message->**

```
 100 2
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "fibag.py", line 27, in <module>
        print(huge_fibo(n,m))
      File "fibag.py", line 21, in huge_fibo
        return get_fibo(rem) % m
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'



#uses python3
def pisano_len(m):
    prev=0
    next=1
    for i in range(m*m+1):
        prev,next=next,(prev+next)%m
        if(prev==0 and next==1):
            return i+1
def get_fibo(n):
    if(n<1):
        return n
    prev=0
    curr=1
    for i in range(n-1):
        (prev,curr)=(curr,prev+curr)
        return curr

def huge_fibo(n,m):
    rem=int(n%pisano_len(m))
    return get_fibo(rem) % m

if(__name__=='__main__'):


    n,m=map(int,input().split())
    print(huge_fibo(n,m))
```

Cant figure out the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `get_fibo()` function does not execute a return statement if `n == 1`, effectively returning `None`.

Answer (score 2):

This bit is strange:

```
for i in range(n-1):
    (prev,curr)=(curr,prev+curr)
    return curr
```

The loop runs 0 or more times, depending on the value of `n`. If it is 1 or less, it runs 0 times, if it is 2, it runs once, in general it runs n-1 times.

But a function *can only return exactly once.* So even if n is 1000, the function will return immediately the first time the loop runs and the rest of the loop never happens.

And if it runs 0 times (n <= 1), there is no return in the loop and the function reaches the end of its code, so that it returns None.

Comment: Thanks, this solved a logical error in the code. But the above response resolved the Type error.

Comment: @varungupta: my last line mentions the same problem. It's both the same logical error. But it's not important who gets a checkmark.